# Undefined reference to a static method

Tags: c++, compilation

I m trying to compile this code and linking fails with the following error:
this is how i m compiling it;

```
g++ logtester.cc -I/home/foo/include -L/home/foo/lib -llog4cxx


/tmp/ccADKreY.o(.text+0x120): In function `main': undefined reference to `FrameworkLogger::getInstance()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why? how can i fix it?

```
#include <log4cxx/logger.h>
#include <log4cxx/xml/domconfigurator.h>

using namespace log4cxx;
using namespace log4cxx::xml;
using namespace log4cxx::helpers;

class FrameworkLogger
{
    private:
        FrameworkLogger();
        LoggerPtr logger;

    public: 
        static LoggerPtr getInstance();

};
```

(Another file:)

```
#include "FrameworkLogger.h"
#include <iostream>

LoggerPtr FrameworkLogger::getInstance()
{
    std::cout<<"test";
}
```

(Yet another file:)

```
#include "FrameworkLogger.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
//      LoggerPtr logger =
        FrameworkLogger::getInstance();
        std::cout<<"test";
}
```

Comment: Can you show your what the compiler invocation looks like?

Comment: I'm willing to bet that your linker line is wrong and misses the file I've named with "Another file" here. Could you please show your compiler invocation?

Comment: I edited the answer and add the compiler invocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a linker error. Ensure that you are properly linking all of your object files

Comment: undefined reference to `FrameworkLogger::getInstance()' , how can this be a linker error? they are all in the same directory. do i need a include in the compilation?

Comment: @DarthVader It _is_ a linker error. The compiler does not yields "undefined reference" error message. When you compile, make sure you specify all the .cpp files.

Answer (score 4):

You need to list all compilation units (.cc files) in the compiler invocation:

```
 g++ logtester.cc the-file-you-have-not-named.cc -I/home/foo/include -L/home/foo/lib -llog4cxx
```